# phpWord - Cannot add PreserveText in Section

Tags: php, phpword

Not got a lot of experience with phpWord and coming across the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Cannot add PreserveText in Section.'

Its happening when using the below line:

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($document_location . $document_name . '.docx');
```

The document definitely exists and I can save the document and readfile as well.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same Problem (also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084148/generate-pdf-from-docx-generated-by-phpword)) and for me loading the document worked after I removed all `mail merge fields` from it. Maybe this works for you, too

Comment: PERFECT!, Thanks for your help. For future notice, anyone with a similar query I highlighted everything in the word document and pressed the following button combination to remove all mailmerge links in the document: ctrl + shift + F9

Comment: Not really a fix, have the same issue but need the mergefields to perform text replacements reliably

Answer (score 2):

For using preserve text in Section add to method `checkValidity()` in file
    `PhpOffice/PhpWord/Element/AbstractContainer.php` new rules.

For example :

in line 214: `'PreserveText'  => array('Header', 'Footer', 'Cell')` add `Section` to array

in line 224: `'PreserveText'  => array(array('Cell'), array('Header', 'Footer'))` add `Section` too for sub containers.

Now, you should write

```
$section->addPreserveText("Total {PAGE} pages.");
```