# Generate PDF from .docx generated by PHPWord

Tags: php, pdf, docx, phpword

I am creating `.docx` files from a template using `PHPWord`. It works fine but now I want to convert the generated file to `PDF`.

First I tried using `tcpdf` in combination with `PHPWord`

```
$wordPdf = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($filename.".docx");

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../Office/tcpdf");
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('TCPDF');

$pdfWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($wordPdf , 'PDF');
if (file_exists($filename.".pdf")) unlink($filename.".pdf");
$pdfWriter->save($filename.".pdf");
```

<s>but when I try to load the file to convert it to `PDF` I get the following exception while loading the file</s>

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Cannot add PreserveText in Section.'

<s>After some research I found that some others also have this bug ([phpWord - Cannot add PreserveText in Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070424/phpword-cannot-add-preservetext-in-section))</s>

**EDIT**

> After trying around some more I found out, that the `Exception` only occurs when I have some `mail merge fields` in my document. Once I removed them the `Exception` does not come up anymore, but the converted `PDF` files look horrible. All style information are gone and I can't use the result, so the need for an alternative stays.

I thought about using another way to generate the PDF, but I could only find 4 ways:

1. **Using [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/)** - Impossible as I cannot install any software on the Server. Also going the way mentioned [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/robertphyatt/archive/2011/11/19/converting-.docx-to-pdf-or-.doc-to-pdf-or-.doc.aspx) did not work either as my hoster ([Strato](https://www.strato.de/)) uses SunOS as the OS and this needs Linux
2. **Using [phpdocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/)** - I do not have any budget to pay for it and the demo cannot create PDF
3. **Using [PHPLiveDocx](http://www.phplivedocx.org/)** - This works, but has the limitation of 250 documents per day and 20 per hour and I have to convert arround 300 documents at once, maybe even multiple times a day
4. **Using [PHP-Digital-Format-Convert](https://github.com/benskay/PHP-Digital-Format-Convert-Epub-Mobi-PDF)** - The output looks better than with `PHPWord` and `tcpdf`, but still not usable as images are missing, and most (not all!) of the styles

Is there a 5th way to generate the PDF? Or is there any solution to make the generated PDF documents look nice?

Comment: Decent PDF output will probably require you to create a second template (you've already got a MSWord template, next you'll want a PDF template taking your source document to the input that tcpdf wants).

Comment: @Rob_M Yeah I already thought about creating a HTML template as there are some librarys to convert HTML to PDF, but I have quite a lot different templates, so it would be quite a lot of work to create them and rewrite the way I fill them with content, so I hope there is another more easy way...

Comment: This link might help:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/311

Comment: PHPWord should do the job, like @hasan.hameed mentioned. As you can't install additional software there shouldn't be any other option to convert it to a nice lookin PDF. My other thought would be using Imagick but this requires the `soffice` binary which shouldn't be installed on strato...

Answer (score 1):

I used [Gears/pdf](https://packagist.org/packages/gears/pdf) to convert the docx file generated by phpword to PDF:

```
$success = Gears\Pdf::convert(
            'file_path/file_name.docx',
            'file_path/file_name.pdf');
```

Comment: Gears is no longer active as of 2022 unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to unlink the PDF file before saving it, and you have also to unlink the DOCX document, not the PDF one.

Try this.

```
$pdfWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($wordPdf , 'PDF');    
$pdfWriter->save($filename.".pdf");
unlink($wordPdf);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'm correct.. 
You save the document as HTML content

> $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');

After than you read the HTML file content and write the content as PDF file with the help of **mPDF** or tcPdf or fpdf.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// get the name of the input PDF
$inputFile = "C:\\PHP\\Test1.docx";

// get the name of the output MS-WORD file
$outputFile = "C:\\PHP\\Test1.pdf";

try
    {
    $oLoader = new COM("easyPDF.Loader.8");
    $oPrinter = $oLoader->LoadObject("easyPDF.Printer.8");
    $oPrintJob = $oPrinter->PrintJob;
    $oPrintJob->PrintOut ($inputFile, $outputFile);
    print "Success";
    }


catch(com_exception $e)
    {
    Print "error code".$e->getcode(). "\n";
    print $e->getMessage();
    }
```